# Prevent Gmail from delivering emails of a thread to the inbox once a label is applied to it

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have a lot of emails to which I apply labels and remove it from the Inbox. However, when a new email in the thread arrives, it again comes to my Inbox (and is also in that label's folder). How do I prevent it from coming it to the inbox? Please note that many a times, there are no specific rules for these (when I do give rules however, I say skip the inbox but otherwise, how to do?)

Comment: I was hoping a filter of "Matches: has:userlabels; Do this: Skip Inbox" would work, but it doesn't. (Labels are actually attached to individual messages, not conversations.) I don't think you can do this natively in Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gmail's [Muting feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47787?hl=en) to automatically have subsequent messages bypass the inbox, but that won't automatically apply the label.  For that, you would need to create a filter action based on the subject line.